# Rails shorthand if/else output html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement

Right now when I use

```
<%= @inbox.automatic_reconciliation ? "<i class='fi-play-circle'></i>" : "<i class='fi-pause'></i>" %>
```

My view spits out the actual code on the page instead of the icon. I've tried using a few methods like .to_html and such to no avail - what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `html_safe` method.

```
<%= @inbox.automatic_reconciliation ? "<i class='fi-play-circle'></i>".html_safe : "<i class='fi-pause'></i>".html_safe %>
```

[documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing this, use the [`raw`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) helper, which is preferred over `html_safe`:

```
<%= raw @inbox.automatic_reconciliation ? "<i class='fi-play-circle'></i>" : "<i class='fi-pause'></i>" %>
```

The better solution by far is to remove this logic from your views. Create a helper method and simply invoke it:

```
<i class="<%= automatic_reconciliation_class %>"></i>
```

Comment: Why is preferred? Except an error raise on `nil`. Both output is a string.

Comment: @Зелёный It is shorter, clearer, less easy to miss and doesn't raise exceptions when the input is `nil`. No, there is no chance of a `nil` input in this case, but the point is that you should standardize on one method, and `raw` is better in the general case. `raw` is a helper method specifically provided for use in your views for exactly this case. Rails is a land of conventions, and you should use `raw` for that reason if no other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator to make it simple:

```
<i class="<%= @inbox.automatic_reconciliation ? "fi-play-circle" : "fi-pause" %>"></i>
```

This embeds the condition directly around the class name, which cleans up the code quite a lot.  Only the name of the class can possibly be affected, so the rest of the HTML is isolated from incidental changes that could lead to maintenance issues in the future.